# Calculate total revenue made from each item broken down by country and day

Tags: mysql, sql, revenue

I have a table which consists:

```
id     country    Date     item_name    price

ae3u2  USA     27/12/2018  budget      1.99
bf5d8  India   31/12/2018  everything  34.99
dc8a4  USA     22/01/2019  cars        25.99
```

and  it goes on.
I have to calculate:

1. total revenue
2. total revenue made from each item broken down by country and day.

I am confused how to calculate it as i don't have "quantity" and i am also not much experienced.

Comment: I guess price is a synonym for revenue..

Comment: I think so but i am not sure as revenue is generally calculated using price and quantity thats why everytime my mind goes towards quantity.

Comment: Can't help you with that..I'm not getting a clue from table name or table contents..if you have doubts go back to whoever gave you this assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `with rollup`, but you will get additional rows:

```
select item_name, country, date, sum(price)
from t
group by item_name, country, date with rollup
```

You can filter out the intermediate rows as:

```
having grouping(item_name, country, date) in (0, 7)
```

Comment: I got the required answer for "Total revenue made from each item broken down by country and day." but i didn't get the use of "having" clause here, can you please explain it ?

Comment: I am also gettting  "Null" values using this query but in the original data there are no null values.

Comment: @ankursingh . . . Those "null" values are on rows that are aggregated.

Comment: Also Can you please explain the use of "having" clause here ? As without using it also answer is the same.  Thanks.

Comment: @ankursingh . . . The `having()` clause should be filtering out certain intermediate results.  The last version does *not* work -- and I don't know why, so I removed it.  Here is a db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab17577d31ae8574cb82e6642fef04f3.